# How to sort multiple field values in order?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field called chocolate_type. There are 4 different chocolate types ("Dark", "White", "Milk", "Sweet"). I want my documents to be sorted in a specific order based on the chocolate type. I do not want to sort the chocolate types in ascending or descending order. Instead, I want them to be sorted where white is first, dark second, milk third, and sweet fourth. Here's an example of how the documents should be sorted:

> id: 5,
>
> chocolate_type: "White"
>
> id: 8,
>
> chocolate_type: "White"
>
> id: 15,
>
> chocolate_type: "Dark"
>
> id: 18,
>
> chocolate_type: "Dark"
>
> id: 24,
>
> chocolate_type: "Dark"
>
> . . .

How can I make a query that does this?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions:

- add some **sort field** to your documents, which will be just a number index corresponding to your chocolate type, but sorting on it will achieve the desired order
- use **script sort** - this sould work without changing your documents. The advantage is that you can change the sort order without reindexing (that is not the case for the first solution), however, performance will be likely worse. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting

Answer (score 0):

So Take one new field **order** in your database and set order number according to your value means for Dark - 1, White - 2, Milk - 3, Sweet-4 
and then do **order by order**.
Let me know if it may help you or not.